# Hide autocomplete bar of keybord in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic.I want to hide auto-complete spelling suggestion bar in ionic. I have installed cordova keyboard plugin but it has method only to hide accessory bar. I have tried many things like

```
autocomplete="off" 
spellcheck="false"
autocorrect="off"
```

I am stuck with this problem for many hours, can any one please help me out with this

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: The code you provided is the only thing I found to disable auto-complete. With this code, on Android, the auto-complete bar is still visible but empty... If someone has a solution, I'm all ears!

Comment: @Mitch when I have tried the above code i was not able to empty the auto-complete bar also.

Comment: I guess it depends on the device you use then. I tested with a Nexus 5.

Comment: can any one please give me the solution.this is the least code i can provide.